# What is best GUI toolkit to rewrite .NET WPF application to C++?

Tags: c++, wpf

We have existing WPF application with complicated graphics (rounded edges of the window, speedometer style indicators etc).

Since we rely on .NET our application needs .NET framework. Some users are unwilling to install .NET and we want to provide them with a version that does not need .NET and runs of Windows only (XP,Vista,W7).

Which graphical toolkit we should use to for this scenario?

So far I think Codejock Toolkit Pro is a good adept as we already have GUI in XAML and it could be easier to port GUI to C++.

However, another aspect is download size of the toolkit. We don't want to end up in the situation where toolkit size is so big (e.g. 20-40MB) that's comparable with .NET 4.0 framework size.

I know some of you might think that going back from WPF to C++ is a bad idea, but for our scenario it is absolutely crucial to make user's installation process as easy as possible and .NET framework is a big stumbling block which we are trying to remove.

Comment: Have you looked at the .NET Client Profile? It will greatly reduce the first installation size for your .NET application, and load the rest of .NET with the next windows update. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc656912.aspx

Comment: yes. we already use .NET client profile. but difference between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.0 client profile is just like 8MB out of 40MB so nothing significant.

Comment: @Janusz which is why they discontinued the concept of client profile in .NET 4.5 and up.

Comment: Some users are unwilling to install .NET, well I would pretty much be telling them to stop being paranoid/stupid or they don't get to use your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I do not have the answer to your question (and I would never ever even dream that I might do such a thing), but I am *compelled* to tell you as an advice

- implementing all the WPF functionality in C++ will take 10-20 times more
- installation of a C++ would not be necessarily easier
- if you need to make installation easier, use **SilverLight**

Comment: Installation of C++ requires copying just a few DLLs.

Comment: You need VC++ runtime library to be installed.

Comment: Yes, and that library is "Redistributable". I.e. you can add it to installer of the App. This adds just 1.5 MB to installer size.

Comment: Silverlight. What a great suggestion. I actually looked into it couple of months ago but our application requires file system and registry access so I dismissed it. Now, I found a way how to do it (e.g. http://wayneye.wordpress.com/tag/out-of-browser/) so it seems Silverlight would be an excellent option. Runtime is only 6MB and installs quickly without need of restarting PC.

Answer (score 1):

We used [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-windows/) in one of our projects in past which is Object Oriented and Multi Platform, but QT is mostly like WinForms

As I remember QT keeps UI in xml files too, try to write XSLT from xaml to QT xml. But I don't thik you can do it in complex WPF structures like Triggers or Animation

Answer (score 0):

Have you evaluated QT? Since this relies on XML for UI definition too, it might be easier to port the code to.

Answer (score 0):

You've already gotten a couple of answers recommending Qt -- and I'd agree that's probably your first choice. Note, however, that while Qt *does* support an XML-based UI description, they *seem* to be moving away from it toward QML, which is based on JavaScript instead.

Another possibility would be wxWidgets, which also supports an XML-based description of the widgets using [XRC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9/overview_xrc.html).